# How can I authorize Google Scope for a DELETE HTTP request on Java?

Tags: java, scope, authorization

I'm trying to DELETE some emails from my organization. I have this code.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/userKey");
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setRequestProperty(
        "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
    httpCon.connect();
```

But I know that its missing the authorization that ask Google. Acording to this page: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/delete

I don't know how to make that happen,

I'm new on this, can you help me please?